# 3D Animation in Java/J2ME?

Tags: java, 3d, opengl-es, java-me

how to do the 3D Animation in java? what are the packages to be needed? i am very newbie about this topic. Sample Code, Tutorials and articles are more thankful. Tell me how i have to start please?

NOTE: its for Mobile Appication.

Comment: Have a look at the tutorial [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/3dgraphics-155829.html). It shows among other things how to produce a demo like this: ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nSgJx.gif) It even goes as far as textures.

Comment: Could you update the link, it redirects to some other page

Answer (score 3):

This article: [Getting Started With the Mobile 3D Graphics API for J2ME](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/3dgraphics-155829.html) seems a nice start as well.

Answer (score 2):

When you say mobile application, are you talking JME or Android? The only JME phones I'm aware of that support 3d are the Siemens mobile and I think they have some sort of proprietary API for it. I believe Android has their own bindings for OpenGL-ES which may remove the requirement for including Jogl (Java binding for OpenGL).